# Cannot launch an activity in android using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, start-activity

I have 2 modules in my application as follow app and interface. interface was an imported aar file.
I am trying to launch an activity in the interface module but every time the application crashes. Launching activities on the app module works fine 
I had tried the other solutions available in this forum but was in vain. Find the codes below

QuestionAnalyser class

```
    package com.example.dell.bubblebot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dell.yandexapilanguagetranslator.Translator;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class QuestionAnalyser extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String question;
    public  static String[] words;
    String entityIdentified;
    static boolean identified = false;
    DatabaseReference entityRef;
    TranslatorServant t = new TranslatorServant();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface);
        Translator.setKey ("trnsl.1.1.20181013T134643Z.debdb5811d6caba2.3a4daf18b25c9f4b97662d5e9ac45ed81b199c84");

    }

    public void analyse(String userQues) {
            TranslatorServant t = new TranslatorServant();
            question = userQues.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d", "");
          //  question = t.translateText(userQues).replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d", "");
              words = question.split(" ");
            getEntity(words);
    }

    private void getEntity(final String[] words) {
                entityRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IRAdata").child("Entities");
                entityRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot entity : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String[] synonyms = entity.child("syn").getValue().toString().split(",");
                            for (String syn : synonyms) {
                                for (String word : words) {
                                    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(syn) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(syn)) {
                                        entityIdentified = entity.getKey();
                                        identified = true;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        check(words);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });
    }


    public void mimicOtherMessage(String message) {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, false);
        Interface.madapter.add(chatMessage);
    }

    public void mimicOtherMessage() {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(null, false);
        Interface.madapter.add(chatMessage);
    }

    public void check(String[] words) {
        if (identified == true) {
            initialiseEntityServant(entityIdentified, question, words);
        }
        if (identified == false) {
            for (String yes : YesNo.yes) {
                for (String w : words) {
                    if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(yes) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                        identified = true;
                        entityIdentified = "basic";
                        initialiseEntityServant(entityIdentified, question, words);
                    }
                }
                for (String no : YesNo.no) {
                    for (String w : words) {
                        if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(no) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                            identified = true;
                            entityIdentified = "basic";
                            initialiseEntityServant(entityIdentified, question, words);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (identified == false) {
            mimicOtherMessage("Sorry, I failed to understand your question.");
        }
    }

    private void initialiseEntityServant(String ent, final String userQues, final String[] words) {
        if (ent.equalsIgnoreCase("cuisine")) {
           cuisine c=new cuisine();
           c.analyse();
        }
        if(ent.equalsIgnoreCase("basic")){
            final List<String> urlsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            final List<String> descList = new ArrayList<String>();
            urlsList.add("https://media.timeout.com/images/103708802/image.jpg");
            urlsList.add("\"https://images.myguide-cdn.com/mauritius/companies/eighty-eight-chinese-restaurant/large/eighty-eight-chinese-restaurant-492783.png");

            descList.add("A Chinese dish of small steamed or fried savoury dumplings containing various fillings. Definitely worth a try");
            descList.add("Traditionally, this Chinese chicken dish is a dry-stir fry — not a lot of sauce is added into Kung Pao chicken. However, with the amount of flavour explosions happening in this dish, you don’t miss OR want any more sauce.");
            Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),gallery.class);
            i.putExtra("urls",urlsList.toArray());
            i.putExtra("desc",descList.toArray());
            startActivity(i);
        }

        // will need to initialise other classes
    }
    //add class to check if question and answer already exists

}
In this code i am calling the gallery activity
```

gallery class:

```
package com.example.dell.bubblebot;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class gallery extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String[]desc;
    public static TextView descTextbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        descTextbox=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc);
        ViewPager viewPager=findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        String[] imageUrls=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");
        String [] descArr=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("desc");
        desc=descArr;
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter= new ViewPagerAdapter(this,imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.samples.chatbotsample1, PID: 14653
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:112)
                      at com.example.dell.bubblebot.QuestionAnalyser.initialiseEntityServant(QuestionAnalyser.java:126)
                      at com.example.dell.bubblebot.QuestionAnalyser.check(QuestionAnalyser.java:93)
                      at com.example.dell.bubblebot.QuestionAnalyser$1.onDataChange(QuestionAnalyser.java:61)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: The `QuestionAnalyser` class appears to extend some `ContextWrapper` class – e.g., `Activity`, `Service`, etc. – and it likely shouldn't. You cannot instantiate those classes yourself.

Comment: No, the QuestionAnalyser class is extending only AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Same thing. Are you using it as an `Activity`? That is, does it actually show on-screen, or is it a utility class? Where and how is `initialiseEntityServant()` being called?

Comment: No it does not. This class is only used for processing. Then how should i call an activity within this class?

Comment: If it doesn't actually show on-screen, it should not extend any `Activity` class or subclass. If you need a `Context` in that class, or even just in that method, then pass a `Context` into it, either via a constructor, or by adding a `Context` parameter to the `initialiseEntityServant()` method.

Comment: I had been trying to solve this for 2 days. I have posted the full code for Question Analyser above. And i  also tried to invoke the class constructor with a class but still this does not seem to work or just maybe i was doing it wrong. Can you please give me an example about how to resolve this?

Comment: Simply do `public class QuestionAnalyser { private Context context; public QuestionAnalyser(Context c) { context = c; } ... }`. Then wherever you get an error because of an unresolved method, call those methods on `context` – e.g., `context.startActivity(i);`.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your quick answer. I will try this and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
Class A { ...
}
```

[getApplicationContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) belongs to abstract class [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context), if you want to use this method in your custom class, the class should extends `Context` or any of its sub class, such as `Application`,`Activity`, etc.

Comment: can you please illustrate an example how can i do that?

Comment: @SamiirahAujub the key is pass a context to the A class, there are many ways.

Comment: I have tried passing a context from  a previous class to class A(QuestionAnalyser) but instead i get an error of android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()